# boost::python: PyErr_Fetch always returns NULL traceback

Tags: python, c++, boost

I've been trying to call Python scripts from C++ code. Everything works fine in general, but when an error in a script occurs and I catch an exception (error_already_set), I'd like to have detailed info on the C++ side, e.g., the line number in the script where the error took place. To fetch this info, I call PyErr_Fetch(&type, &value, &traceback) and always fail to get a non-NULL traceback and then extract the details. A really strange thing is that subsequent calls to PyErr_Print() all the time succeed and I observe detailed error info on the screen. The problem is that I need this info in a string in my C++ code, not just on the screen. 
If you have any ideas which way to go and what to try, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

This is the member function, in which Python scripts are invoked by the indices:

```
void ScriptManager::ExecPythonScript(unsigned Index) 
{
   GILManager lock;
   try {
      object result = exec(mScripts[Index].c_str(), mMain);
      mRetValues[Index] = extract<std::string>(mMain["retVal"]);
   }
   catch (const error_already_set&) {
      PyObject* ptype;
      PyObject* pvalue;
      PyObject* ptraceback;
      PyErr_Fetch(&ptype, &pvalue, &ptraceback); // ptraceback is always NULL
      // PyErr_Print(); // works fine
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you share code which misbehaves? Preferably in a way somebody else can compile it and test. And with irrelevant parts removed. We don't know how you initialize python parser, how you call it, what kind of exception is escaping out of python script, if you normalize exception received from PyErr_fetch, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found out that traceback is NULL for certain types of script errors (e.g., syntax errors) and all related info is returned in the second argument (value).